# OpenGL: Rendering lots of cubes

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, rendering, voxel

I am trying to create a 600x600x600 grid containing unit cubes (or spheres). Only some of the cubes are present. So, basically I'm trying to have something like the following made up of small cubes or spheres.

[image: A 3D Shadow Hull]

**Question 1**: Rendering such a structure is costly. It requires 3 nested loops (each of 600 iterations). Is there any way to deal with that?

What I thought is to combine the nearby cubes into a single one (oct-trees), since there won't be too many gaps in my case. But I want a general solution to this. How long do you think it would have taken to render such a scene above (seems like a scene of 250x250x250)?

**Question 2**: Is instance rendering related to my problem?

**Note**: Here I'm representing voxel as a cube which in turn needs 6 quads.

Answer (score 3):

I have done voxel rendering engines in the past. Here are some quick optimizations that I can suggest that will give you a good speed boost:

1. Use geometric culling algorithm to cull bits that are not being rendered. I use oct-trees since they go nicely with voxels.
2. Sort your visible nodes front to back and use some algorithm to determine which nodes will not be visible at all. Also, make good use of occlusion culling.
3. Use geometry shaders like others have suggested.
4. Have an LOD scheme in place. In simple words, if two cubes can be joined into one and the result will be imperceptible to the user then do it. Good LOD scheme can greatly reduce the amount of data that you are rendenring.
5. Remember that the best polygon is the one that's not drawn at all :).

Done properly these three things will give you a big chunk of the boost that you're looking for. After that its all fine tuning to your needs and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed Problem 1 can be handled by combining various cubes into one big cube. Voxel engines often group multiple individual boxes together in chunks. That is perhaps the best way to go.
Secondly, you can use a boolean variable for each voxel, as well as for the chunk containing those voxels and set it 1 for being rendered or 0 otherwise.
You will require a voxel class, a chunk class, and some other abstractions depending on your requirements.

Comment: I've all the class structure. The main problem is iterating. Combining cubes won't work when you have a checkboard structure (when no cube is adjacent to any other cube). Do you have any general solution? Any change in shader and all that?
Also, is it feasible to store 600x600x600 boolean variables.

Comment: Check-board structure makes things rather complicated. I am yet to think of a plausible answer. Though you can try https://sites.google.com/site/letsmakeavoxelengine/home for some references.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps creating a geometry shader that replicate a box for every point in a mesh. Program the shader intelligent so that it does not output sides turned away from View and no sides where there is an "active" box adjacent.

The problem is to supply the geometry shader the 600*600*600 sized boolean values. If the composite "object" is somewhat solid perhaps you only need to supply the starting and ending positions on each row/column of cubes, so: 1,4,90,345 means fill position from 1 to 4 and from 90 to 345 with cubes.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

I dont' know how you come up with rendering 3 nested loops. I see one huge loop with 600^3 voxels. The last thing you want to do is render every voxel by itself one by one, since your GPU is a streaming multicore processor, and your data is virtually the same, except for a translation in space. To be fair, that number is probably a bit too high to begin with. Currently it takes about 64.000 cubes to render at 11ms, though you can probably get it even faster if you have a static scene setup. See: [SVO Rendering: OpenGL or Custom renderer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207919/svo-rendering-opengl-or-custom-renderer/25868207#25868207)

Anther thing you can do is LOD the scene, i.e. only render what is really necessary. Are you really interested in voxels that lie far away? If they are of sub-pixel size, you can just as well render a quad imposter instead.

**Question 2:**

Instance rendering is definately part of the solution, as are VBO's and VAO's, but there are other means like sending only coordinates and generate the actual geometry in a geometry shader. See also http://sol.gfxile.net/instancing.html

If you have a static scene, you can have another almost 5x performance increase.